# Do these converge for $p>0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Do these converge for **all** $p>0$?

- $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{n}{n^p +e^{-n}}$
- $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^ne^{-np}$

The first one, using the alternate series test, we can see that it is always decreasing but greater than $0$ for every value of $p$, and limit is
$0$, so the series converges.

The second one has a similar pattern and also decreases in the same way. Can I also say that it converges by the alternate series test?

Comment: I don't get that the limit is zero for the first sum, are you sure about that? Your argument for the second sum seems reasonable though, you can also show this using the ratio test.

Answer (score 1):

The second sum converges by the alternate series test, but not the first. The limit of the terms of the first sum is $(-1)^n/p$, and it's not hard to show that such a sum would diverge, jumping between two values separated by $1/p$. You can not use the alternative series test for the series because the limit of it's terms is not zero. For example, consider:

$\sum_{i=1}^\infty (1+\frac{-1^n}{i})$, or even $\sum_{i=1}^\infty ((-1)^i+\frac{-1^n}{i})$

They clearly diverge, the first one going to infinity and the second oscilating between $-1$ and $1$ (Or values close to it) but their terms are absolutly decreasing.